# How to render a component inside another component angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular10

I have a situation in which I have to render a component inside another component just like a `div` inside another `div`. Let's suppose there are two components `HStack` & `Button`, I want to be able to do something like this from any other component using the above two:

```html
<HStack>
  <Button>Similar kind of nesting here!</Button>
</HStack>
```

How can I achieve this? **Any help will be highly appreciated!!**

Comment: You can use <ng-content> </ng-content> into your parent component template.

Answer (score 3):

What you’re looking for is [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection).

Sample code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'HStack',
  template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
`
})
export class HStack {}
```

How to use:

```html
<HStack>
  <Button>Similar kind of nesting here!</Button>
</HStack>
```